# OpenGL EXTension not detected by GLEW?

Tags: opengl, glew, wgl

I'm writing some modules using "**DirectStateAccess**" capabilities. If it's not supported, I made the necessary stuff.

On a customer laptop, I was able to create an OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile context. In a first call to `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`, `GL_EXT_direct_state_access` was available.

However, GLEW_EXT_direct_state_access variable definitely equals false. 
Subsequent call to `wglGetProcAddress("glTextureParameteriEXT")` returns a non null value though. And the functions `glTextureParameterxx()` seem available as well...

At this point, I wonder if I can rely on GLEW variables to check if an extension is indeed supported or not.

Oh, by the way, I made my tests with a "valid OpenGL context activated"...

Comment: Are you also setting `glewExperimental` to `GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit()`?

Comment: Yes I did it though.

Comment: Seems this is already filed as a bug [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/glew/bugs/167/).